# WARNING: API 'variant.getMergeAssets()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getMergeAssetsProvider()'

Tags: android-studio, augmented-reality, arcore

I want to create a simple AR project, however I get this message when I try to create a .sfb file from .fbx file. This is my first time with AR, and I am not really into Android so much, so I don't really know what to do.

Answer (score 3):

Just change:

```
string variant.mergeAssets.doLast {
```

to:

```
variant.mergeAssetsProvider.get().doLast {
```

It will work.

Comment: Thanks, it worked for my cocos creator 2.4.2 project

Answer (score -1):

you can move to a previous gradle version and it will get fixed.